IdP initialted SSO redirects back to the IDP stub
I am trying to implement IdP-initiated Sso login on my angular app and IdentityServer4 environment. My setup is as follows
Angular app is runngin on http://localhost:4200
IdentityServer4 is running on http://localhost:7000
I use Sustainsys.Saml2 library to implement ServiceProvider part.
Here are my codes
IdentitServer4
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddCookie()
.AddSaml2("Saml2", "Login with SSO", opt =>
{
    opt.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    opt.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    opt.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId("http://localhost:7000/Saml2/");
    opt.SPOptions.ReturnUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:4200/idp-redirect?idp=Saml2");


    // Idp using a custom query string param on the Acs URL.
    opt.IdentityProviders.Add(new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/1b1f27d2-1d59-46aa-8756-3597337da1fe/Metadata"), opt.SPOptions)
    {
        LoadMetadata = true,
        AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true,
    });

    opt.Notifications.AcsCommandResultCreated = AcsCommandResultCreated;
}); 

private static void AcsCommandResultCreated(CommandResult commandResult, Saml2Response saml2Response)
{          
    var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    var target = httpContext.Request.Query["target"].SingleOrDefault();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(target))
    {            
        var targetUri = new Uri(target, UriKind.Relative);
        if (target.StartsWith("//"))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Protocol relative URLs are not allowed.");
        }

        commandResult.Location = targetUri;
    }
}

ExternalController.cs in IdentityServer4
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback()
{
    // read external identity from the temporary cookie
    var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
    if (result?.Succeeded != true)
    {
        throw new Exception("External authentication error");
    }

    if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Debug))
    {
        var externalClaims = result.Principal.Claims.Select(c => $"{c.Type}: {c.Value}");
        _logger.LogDebug("External claims: {@claims}", externalClaims);
    }

    // lookup our user and external provider info
    var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
    if (user == null)
    {
        //getting user data from my database        
         string email = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
        
        Member _member = await _memberDal.GetAsync(x => x.Email == email);
        if (_member == null)
        {
            user = null;
        }
        else
        {
            user = new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = _member.Email,
                Username = _member.FirstName + " " + _member.LastName,
            };
        }
            
    }

    // this allows us to collect any additional claims or properties
    // for the specific protocols used and store them in the local auth cookie.
    // this is typically used to store data needed for signout from those protocols.
    var additionalLocalClaims = new List<Claim>();
    var localSignInProps = new AuthenticationProperties();
    ProcessLoginCallback(result, additionalLocalClaims, localSignInProps);

    // issue authentication cookie for user
    var isuser = new IdentityServerUser(user.SubjectId)
    {
        DisplayName = user.Username,
        IdentityProvider = provider,
        AdditionalClaims = additionalLocalClaims
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(isuser, localSignInProps);

    // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

    // retrieve return URL
    var returnUrl = result.Properties.Items["returnUrl"] ?? "~/";

    // check if external login is in the context of an OIDC request
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    await _events.RaiseAsync(new UserLoginSuccessEvent(provider, providerUserId, user.SubjectId, user.Username, true, context?.Client.ClientId));

    if (context != null)
    {
        if (context.IsNativeClient())
        {
            // The client is native, so this change in how to
            // return the response is for better UX for the end user.
            return this.LoadingPage("Redirect", returnUrl);
        }
    }

    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}

I used the below samples
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/v1/docs/identity-server-3-okta.rst
https://github.com/Sustainsys/AspNetcoreIdpInitiated/blob/main/AspNetCoreIdpInitiated/Startup.cs
The problem is that the angular app does not get a token for the first time. when I click the My Account link it redirects IdentityServer again to check if I logged in successfully. I realized IdentityServer logged me in and successfully redirected me to the angular app.
I think returnUrl was not generated correctly but I am not sure how to generate that.
Any help would be appreciated.
UPDATE :
Here are the identityServer logs
2024-10-01 15:43:23 info: Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler[0]
2024-10-01 15:43:23       Successfully processed SAML response id752f7f4f578f4b788a86572bfa7d1f8d and authenticated JohnDoe
2024-10-01 15:43:25 info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
2024-10-01 15:43:25       Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize    
2024-10-01 15:43:26 info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
2024-10-01 15:43:26       Showing login: Current IdP (local) is not the requested IdP (Saml2)
2024-10-01 15:43:39 info: Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler[0]
2024-10-01 15:43:39       Initiating login to https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/1b1f27d2-1d59-46aa-8756-3597337da1fe/Metadata
2024-10-01 15:43:47 fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
2024-10-01 15:43:47       An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
2024-10-01 15:43:47       Sustainsys.Saml2.Exceptions.UnexpectedInResponseToException: Received message id393c68a4474d4692a2d0736ec17abc40 contains unexpected InResponseTo "id7a9f26358b48447a87db08d760e155a5". No cookie preserving state from the request was found so the message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute. This error typically occurs if the cookie set when doing SP-initiated sign on have been lost.
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.ValidateInResponseTo(IOptions options, IEnumerable`1 claimsIdentities)
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Sustainsys.Saml2.Saml2P.Saml2Response.GetClaims(IOptions options, IDictionary`2 relayData)
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.ProcessResponse(IOptions options, Saml2Response samlResponse, StoredRequestState storedRequestState, IdentityProvider identityProvider, String relayState)
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.AcsCommand.Run(HttpRequestData request, IOptions options)
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Handler.HandleRequestAsync()
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at IdentityServer4.Hosting.FederatedSignOut.AuthenticationRequestHandlerWrapper.HandleRequestAsync()
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
2024-10-01 15:43:47          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I also update my cookie settings as below
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => SameSiteCookieHelper.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext => SameSiteCookieHelper.CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);        

    //this is important. this will help you to solve the problem.
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
});

SameSiteCookieHelper Class is as follows
public static class SameSiteCookieHelper
{
    public static void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
    {
        if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
        {
            if (!BrowserSupportsSameSiteNone(httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString()))
            {
                // Unspecified - no SameSite will be included in the Set-Cookie.
                options.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool BrowserSupportsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
    {
        // iOS 12 browsers don't support SameSite=None.
        if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") || userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // macOS 10.14 Mojave browsers don't support SameSite=None.
        if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") && userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Old versions of Chrome don't support SameSite=None.
        if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

UPDATE 2:
the system starts from IDP which is stubidp in this case. then redirects user to angular app and then create an auth request url from angular app and redirect user to IdentityServer to check saml response and authenticate user. I think user should redirect back to the angular app at this point but IdentityServer redirect user to the stubidp again. Is it the correct way to authenticate user on IDP initiated flow? I think system should not redirect back to the stubidp from identityServer



you must use HTTPS with IdentityServer, because you will otherwise loose cookies on the way (due to samesite restrictions). I blogged about troubleshooting cookie problems at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

I tried but it did not help... ): thanks anyway

For example,     //this is important. this will help you to solve the problem.
options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;, requires HTTPS and the cookie secure attribute, otherwise that cookie will be rejected.  I would use a tool like https://getfiddler.com/ to explore the requests being sent back and forth.

the system starts from IDP which is stubidp in this case. then redirects user to angular app and then create an auth request url from angular app and redirect user to IdentityServer to chack saml response and authenticate user.  I think user should redirect back to the angular app at this point but IdentityServer redirect user to the stubidp again. Is it the correct way to authenticate user on IDP initiated flow? I think system should not redirect back to the stubidp from identityServer?

Its hard to tell from the outside, why it does not work.

Here is an update to my question.
the issue is related with the cookie settings.
you must use https and set sameSite settings to none. right now our system is behind a load balancer and runs on http. SSL is terminated on load balancer.
